# JavaScript get date and time from timestamp

Tags: javascript, date

I have this field as part of a web response:

```
datetime_local: "2015-02-16T19:00:00"
```

Can I extract the date and time? For instance I would like to display

```
February 16th at 7pm
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You may be interested in looking into the moment.js library: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: If you are able to use an external library, take a look at @Pinal 's answer. This momentjs library will save you a lot of fussing with times.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function

```
function getFormattedDate(date)
{
var fortnightAway = new Date(date),
        date = fortnightAway.getUTCDate(),
        hour = fortnightAway.getUTCHours(),
        month = "January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December"
      .split(",")[fortnightAway.getUTCMonth()];

    function nth(d) {
      if(d>3 && d<21) return 'th'; // thanks kennebec
      switch (d % 10) {
            case 1:  return "st";
            case 2:  return "nd";
            case 3:  return "rd";
            default: return "th";
        }
    }

return month+" "+date+nth(date) +" at "+(hour<12?hour+"am":(hour-12)+"pm");   
}
```

Call it like `getFormattedDate("2015-02-16T19:00:00")`

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaCnL/53/)**

Comment: @void : Without 'Z' (e.g. "2015-02-16T19:00:00Z") or without timezone, your Fiddle give different result in IE/FF/Chrome (local or UTC)...  `new Date(date)` parsing algorithms are implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You can using [momentjs.com](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) for formatting:

```
moment(Date.parse("2015-02-16T19:00:00")).format("MMMM Do [at] hhA");
// February 16th at 10PM
```

Comment: Include the at word by escaping it - `moment('2015-02-16T19:00:00').format('MMMM Do [at] h:mm a');`

Comment: This produces February 16th at 12PM which is incorrect, seems to be treating the date as GMT-7